# I rented a car in Buffalo and drove to Canada. I am not a US Citizen. The land border is closed to non-essential travel. Can I drive back?

Tags: borders

Car rented in Buffalo on US plates.  I am a non-US Citizen or Resident.  Can I drive back to the USA?

Comment: Do you have a reason to return to the US, or do you simply want to return the rental car?  The list of allowed "essential" activities is actually quite long: "work and study, critical infrastructure support, economic services and supply chains, health, immediate medical care, safety and security, trade and business travel"

Comment: Did you tell the rental company in US that you were driving to Canada? What did they say? Is it covered by the terms of the rental, and insurance?

Comment: Perhaps you could befriend a US citizen who could drive the car into the US and return it for you. Of course, depending on that person's status and relationships, their return to Canada could itself be problematic.

Comment: Are you planning on returning from Buffalo to Canada after you return the car (in which case you'll need a COVID test, and quarantine plans if you're not vaccinated/don't fill out the ArriveCAN forms)? How? My guess would be that the US border guards *would* let you across, but more information would be very useful.